# How can I 5-star the Zaltys?

Tags: lightning-returns-demo

The Zaltys is the end boss of the demo.  He's big and mean and has a ton of health.  It takes me forever to kill him, and my swords do very little damage to him.  I only got two stars!

What's an easy way to get five stars on him?

Answer (score 4):

One of the main tricks to help yourself is to use Libra to figure out what he's weak to.  He halves physical damage, and magical damage is only normal to him.  Ice, however, he's really weak to, so go heavy with the Black Mage's Quick Freeze.

A super simple way to stagger him and end the fight quickly is to use the Dragoon schemata, just as is.  Use Beat Down, and it turns into Jump.  Use that, and it will almost always stagger him, since physical attacks to the head are one of his stagger conditions.

Once he's staggered, go to town on him.  The Red Mage's Buster Ruin can extend his stagger time, so use that a couple times.  Make sure to cast Deprotect on him as well.  Switch to Dragoon, and smash him as hard as you can.  You can blow through a lot of your AP using Beat Down and Jump, and it will do a ton of damage to him, especially with Deprotect active.

Once you run out of AP, use the Overdrive.  That will extend the stagger time, and fill up all your schemata's AP.  Since you have enough EP to Overdrive twice, burn through it once, and use up all the AP on your current schema, if possible, before he gets back up.  Once he starts standing up, use the last one, and just hit him with everything you have.  Between Deprotect, the Dragoon's attack power, and the Black Mage's Quick Freeze, he should be a very quick kill.

I got five stars with a time of 2:02, so it seems pretty generous in how you can do it.

Comment: Well you certainly figured that out pretty fast!

Comment: @MichaelFrank, Frank has likely answered the question at the same time as posting the question. We encourage such practice when you have already solved a problem you encounter, and can not find a solution on here. That way, other users may find a solution quicker, if they come on with the same question. The only issue with the self-answer feature is that you can not immediately accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Purchase a warriors potion, and an enfrost potion. The warriors potion will give you bravery and faith, to increase physical damage, when the boss is staggered. The enfrost potion will make your attacks inflict ice-based damage, but will not be very effective, unless the boss is staggered.

Place deprotect on the savior schemata, and use it, then use both the potions. Switch to the dragoon schemata, and use beat down to access the jump ability. Timed correctly, with the effects of both potions, should inflict an easy 13,000 damage.

Switch to the red mage schemata, and use light slash, until the stagger effect is over. Each light slash should inflict a further 1900-2500 damage. You should easily defeat the boss before your initial stagger is over.